# Does lightning out consumes APIs?

Tags: lightning, lightning-out

In the documentation there is no mention of apis consumption by lightning out.
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/lightning_out_considerations.htm
Since lightning out could be hosted on heroku or any other platform, I assume that it could get data from salesforce only by APIs. So does this consume APIs or not?

Has anyone tried what happens to APIs consummption when lightning out app is used out of salesforce like heroku?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When Lightning Out App is used there is no consumption of any API calls .

Just tested with couple of lightning out POC I have for DF16 .The way lightning out runs is it uses connected app for session Id and then it does not use any SOAP or the REST API calls of the platform and instead it uses @AuraEnabled classes and hence no usage was logged in my org when i tested .